# Permissions issue when installing yarn in a docker image

Tags: docker, permissions, yarnpkg

My dev team is currently setting up the environment for the updates on a proyect we've developing. I'm going straight to the point.

In our `DockerFile` we are installing yarn with `RUN npm install -g yarn`
But when executing an `.sh` file that empties cache files, we got the error:

```
yarn error “EACCESS: permission denied, scandir '/root/.config/yarn/link'”
```

I've looking up for possible fixes, and we only found a workaround which is to give full permissions to that directory:

```
RUN chmode -R 777 '/root/
```

And we know this is highly not recommended.
Does anyone know a better answer? I've seen tons of issues like this one with yarn and docker.

Yarn version is 1.9.4

Edit1:
The problem is that yarn writes or read these file with the user that executes this action, so the solution would be to grant permission to all user. Maybe in a more retrictive way?

EDIT:

After lots of failures we decided to just use chmode -R 777 ~/.config && chmode -R 777 ~/.cache Those files were not created until we ran a yarn install, what due to how we developed the sistem, was triggered everytime an user entered the sistem. So the workaround was to just give 777 permissions to every user in order to let them write onto these files.

Anyway, if anything better comes up, I'll post the answer here.

Btw the system got deprecated

Comment: Which base image are you using?

Comment: I would not worry _that_ much, because it's file permissions _inside_ your docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this In `dockerfile`

`USER root`

`RUN npm install -g yarn`

`USER [user name]`

`RUN chown -R [user name] ~/.config && chown -R [user name] ~/.cache`

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: This is not working, I think because those directories are not created until I execute a yarn run .

Comment: And thats why I had to use RUN chmode -R 777 '/root/

Comment: Then I would prefer `chmode -R 777 ~/.config && chmode -R 777 ~/.cache`

Comment: I tried replacing the line RUN chmode -R 777 /root/ with chmod -R 777 ~/.config and ended in the same issue

Comment: I couldnt make it work, Im still trying to access to root files as an user and getting EACCESS permission denied.

Comment: What's the base image you are using?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo npm install yarn && yarn install
```

Answer (score -4):

We ended up setting 777 permissions, but that system got deprecated.

Comment: Disclaimer: this is extremely not recommended, so if you have a similar problem, dont use this as a workaround.